# Using n-gram with R for error correction

Tags: r, nlp, ocr, n-gram

I'm working on a project to correct errors from scanned documents by an OCR and I would use n-grams with R.
My algorithm would be first trained using a corpus with know mistakes to create a confusion
matrix of 3-gram. So that when I have a particular 3-gram I can know what is the most probable 
3-gram to replace it when there's a mistake.

For know I only manage to create n-gram for a sentence:

```
library(tau)
library(tm)

txt1 <- "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."

r1<-textcnt(txt1, method = "ngram", n=3)
data.frame(counts = unclass(r1), size = nchar(names(r1)))
format(r1)
```

But it gives me the frequency of each 3-gram without keeping the order and I  can't use it to create a confusion matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the package `tm`, you'll need to use an outside tokenizer according to this part of their documentation: http://tm.r-forge.r-project.org/faq.html#Bigrams

But this should be pretty straightforward and there are many ways to accomplish your goal.

3-gram analysis:

```
library(tau)
temp <- "I would gladly pay you Tuesday for a hamburger today."
textcnt(temp, method="ngram", n=3L, decreasing=TRUE)
```

This is how you create a confusion matrix:

```
library(MASS)
iris.lda <- lda(Species ~ . , data = iris)
table(predict(iris.lda, type="class")$class, iris$Species)
```

If you need tokens (in a term-document matrix) of length 3, you could use a 3-gram tokenizer (n = 3). See e.g., http://tm.r-forge.r-project.org/faq.html#Bigrams.

You can use the dictionary argument to store only your selection:

```
yourTokenizer <- function(x) RWeka::NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 3, max = 3))
TermDocumentMatrix(crude, control = list(tokenize = yourTokenizer, dictionary = yourDictionary))
```

The corresponding example from the `tm` documentation was:

```
library("RWeka")
library("tm")
data("crude")
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
inspect(tdm[340:345,1:10])
```

Comment: Thank for your help but it's not exactly what I am looking for, I agree that I did not explained really well...
I would like to compare identical sentences except that the second one will have faults, ex: "paq" and "pay" the confusion matrix will tell me that next time I see "paq" I should replace it with "pay"

Comment: I see. Sorry, I didn't get that. Offhand, I do not know how to do that in R, but it's definitely do-able because I could tell you how to do it in other languages. If I get some free time tonight or tomorrow morning I'll try to follow up.

Comment: Do you know how to it in python for example? Thank you for your help

Comment: I know I saw a good example in C. There's probably one in Python. I did a quick search to try to find what I was looking at yesterday, but I'm at work and I wasn't able to quickly track it down this second. However, I thought you might like this paper: http://www.ijcsit.com/docs/Volume%204/Vol4Issue1/ijcsit2013040122.pdf